# Azure blob policy - auto upload JSON rules

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I want to configure blob's policy to remove unnecessary entries and I prepare JSON with rules, which can do it. This file has to be upload it by Azure Portal.

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "ruleFoo",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
          "prefixMatch": [ "container1/foo" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "tierToCool": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30 },
            "tierToArchive": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 90 },
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 2555 }
          },
          "snapshot": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 90 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My purpose is to avoid manually upload. Does anyone know how it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an `Azure Blob storage lifecycle rule`, you cannot directly upload the .json file.

Here are 2 ways workaround to automatically create the rule:

1.Use [azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-powershell#add-or-remove-a-policy) directly, or if you still consider using .json file, you need to use powershell to read the values from .json file, then use [azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-powershell#add-or-remove-a-policy) with the values from .json file.

2.Use the [Management Policies - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/managementpolicies/createorupdate#storageaccountsetmanagementpolicies) rest api, or if you still consider using .json file, use code(.net or other programming language) to read the values from .json first, then fill in each field in the rest api.

If you still have more issues like don't know how to use azure powershell or rest api, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, however you can use JSON files and upload via Powershell which can be automated using a script. You can read about it at the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/programmatically-create

(Once I'm able, I'll edit this to include an example.)